# Gem::FilePermissionError when installing RoR bundle on Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I am trying to install the *RoR* bundle on Linux. When I run `gem install bundler` I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please, provide information about your linux distro.

Are you using rvm?

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: Lubuntu and I ran - gem install bundler

Comment: What is the output of command `which ruby`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the root permission to access.

Try:

```
sudo -u root -p
```

where `u` denotes *User* and `p` denotes *password*.

Your root user password can be the answer for this. 
After that run:
"**gem update --system**
"**gem install json**